# FTP Access erro : ftraise NotImplementedError NotImplementedError

Tags: python, ftp, pyftpsync

I am using one rhc openshift server.

So ii is installed python on it and i installed ***pyftpsync*** module on its, so i want to connect to anther host via ftp, but i got this error:

```
 res = self._sync_dir()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/56856e180c1e6670500000bb/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/synchronizers.py", line 375, in _sync_dir
    remote_entries = self.remote.get_dir()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/56856e180c1e6670500000bb/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 270, in get_dir
    self.ftp.retrlines("MLSD", _addline)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/56856e180c1e6670500000bb/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 443, in retrlines
    callback(line)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/56856e180c1e6670500000bb/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 263, in _addline
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Mys sorce code are here:

```
cd /tmp

cat << 'EOF' > ftp_sync.py
from ftpsync.synchronizers import DownloadSynchronizer, UploadSynchronizer,BiDirSynchronizer

from ftpsync.targets import FsTarget #, UploadSynchronizer, DownloadSynchronizer
from ftpsync.ftp_target import FtpTarget
import os

env_var = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR']

local = FsTarget('/tmp')

passwd = "ss123456"

ip='sa1sss.atspace.cc';user='2025575';#  sa1sss.atspace.cc XXXX@yahoo.om




remote = FtpTarget("/mashhadpc.tk", ip,21, user, passwd)

opts = {"force": False, "delete_unmatched": False, "verbose": 3, "execute": True, "dry_run" : False}

s = UploadSynchronizer(local, remote, opts)

s.run()
stats = s.get_stats()
print(stats)
EOF

nohup sh -c " ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/python/bin/python ftp_sync.py"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync.log
```

So As you can see there is ftp user and pass free for your test its connections,So what is my mistake in writing this codes,which causes to got that error.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs, the The FTP server must support the [MLSD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#page-23) command.
The error indicates, that the response of this command could not be parsed.
I would suggest, that you open an issue on the pyftpsync project site.